# Is there a regex to filter only the numbers from a string like this "21312+234234-4224.675-.1342X5646"?

Tags: javascript, regex

So far, i've tried this `const regexOpe = /^\-?\d*?\.?\d+\d$/g;`
however,its just matching the whole string. where did i go wrong?
I wanted use this regex to filter out numbers from a string which contains "+","-","X","/","." and number strings.
Regex should match numbers, negative sign and the decimal point.

The regex im looking for should filter out the string as follows,
["21312","234234","-4224.675","-.1342","5646"]

Comment: You'll find all you need in the (Regex Cheatsheet)https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Cheatsheet) - assuming you even know how to write any regex

Comment: @JaromandaX been at it for a long time, couldn't figure out a way. will be very helpful you know a way. thanks in advance

Comment: so, you've tried regex's? what's the regex that gives you the closest result to what you want - put that in the question - it shows you aren't just asking for someone to do your code for you, and that you actually tried - it's a requirement on stack overlow - to try and solve your issue

Comment: @JaromandaX oh im sorry, ill be careful next time beginner mistake

Comment: shouldn't ".1342"  be "-.1342"  ?

Comment: @KeithNicholas yeah your right, ill make a change

Comment: @salmanthasleem figured as much, my answer assumed that you wanted the negative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this problem using the combination of [replaceAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll) and [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).

You can split the regex into three forms as:

All the below regex parts are in **OR (|)**, if either one is true then it will replace with `_`

**1)** `[^-\.\d]` This part of regex says *don't select if it a `digit` or `-` or `.` Select any other character apart from these three*

[image]

**2)** `[-.](?!\d)` It says *select symbol from `-` or `.` if it is not followed by a `digit`*. It covers `675-.1342X5646` where we have to remove the `-`.

[image]

**3)** `(?<=\d)(?=-)` This is the most interesting part it says *select a `position` where on the left side there will be a `digit` and on the right side there will be a `-`*. It covers the `234234-4224` in which we have to get `234234` and `-4224` separately

```js
const str = "21312+234234-4224.675-.1342X5646";

const result = str.replaceAll(/[^-\.\d]|[-.](?!\d)|(?<=\d)(?=-)/g, "_").split("_");

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Is it possible for someone to give me an explanation on how this particular regex works?

Comment: couldn't have put it better

Comment: took me a while to notice i made a mistake, regex 2) - \[-.](?!\d)\ is completely unnecessary  the expected outcome can be achieved by using 1) and 3) regexes, thanks to  @KeithNicholas for pointing out my mistake

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like the following

```js
let re=/(-?\d*\.\d*|-?\d+)/g
let matches = "21312+234234-4224.675-.1342X5646".match(re)
console.log(matches)
```